# Convertir una imagen a gris y luego aplicarle degradado Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando convertir una imagen a gris y luego aplicarle degradado vertical, he logrado aplicarle el degradado, pero cuando quiero convertirla a gris el codigo explota

```
import numpy as np # funciones numéricas (arrays, matrices, etc.)
from PIL import Image
src = np.array(Image.open('C:/Users/Car/Desktop/foto.jpg'))  
src1 = src.convert('L')
mask1 = np.array(Image.open('C:/Users/Car/Desktop/degra.jpg').resize(src1.shape[1::-1], Image.BILINEAR))
mask1 = mask1 / 255
dst = src1 * (1 - mask1)
imshow(dst.astype(np.uint8))
show()
```

Comment: ¿Explota? Explicate mejor

Comment: Además de lo que dijo Candid Moe, el código que publicaste tiene un error. imshow y show no existen. Pero dudo que ese sea el error del que hablas. Por favor, podrías aclarar el error y hacer de tu [ejemplo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Por cierto, los numpy.ndarray no tienen (o al menos no está documentado) un método llamado convert. No habrás querido decir `np.array(Image.open('C:/Users/Car/Desktop/foto.jpg').convert("L"))`. Los objetos Pil.Image.Image SI tienen un método convert.